# Spring WebSecurity allow access from url

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I need to allow a certain request through my security but I only want to allow it if it is coming from a certain location to a specific place on my server. Here is my current Security Config pertaining to WebSecurity:

```
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception
    {
        web
        .ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/authentication/login")
        .antMatchers("/users/create")
        .antMatchers("/services/**")
        .antMatchers("/favicon.ico")
        .antMatchers("/resources/**")
        .antMatchers("/leagues/signupDetails/**");

        // allow from https://connect.stripe.com/
        // to
        // "/stripeAccountConfirm"
    }
```

I'm sure there is a way to do this, but I am new to the whole configuration scene. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with Web Security Expressions:

```
...
.antMatchers("/services/**").access("hasRole('admin') and hasIpAddress('192.168.10.0/32')")
...
```